# print javascript variable as an attribute in html tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
var disabled = '';
if(value.action.length === 0)
{
  disabled = 'disabled="disabled"';
}
row += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="create" value="1" class="checkbox" data-action="'+ value.action + '" data-controller = "'+ value.controller +'" data-role="'+ role +'" document.write(disabled)></td>';
```

I want to print `disabled="disabled"` based on the truthfulness of my condition. In PHP this can be easily done by the method I used above but I failed to to it in JavaScript. The `document.write()` is getting printed as it is.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You don't need `document.write` here, simply concat the strings as you did before: `… + '" ' + disabled + '></td>';` or even with less code: `… + '"' + ( value.action.length === 0 ? ' disabled' : '' ) +  '></td>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need document.write. Just like this:

```
if(value.action.length === 0)
{
    disabled = 'disabled="disabled"';
}else{
    disable = '';
}
row += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="create" value="1" class="checkbox" data-action="'+ value.action + '" data-controller = "'+ value.controller +'" data-role="'+ role +'" '+ disabled +'></td>';
```

Comment: Yep, and disabled="disabled" is unnecessary. just "disabled" would suffice, because it's a HTML bool. disabled="false" would also disable it.

Comment: so:
var disabled = (value.action.length ===0) ? "disabled" : "";

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I focused too much on this contatenation. Already edited.

Comment: yes i done that. That was a silly thing i was doing :)